# How to restrict user notification about call recording on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, call-recording

Recently with new android OS update google launched feature if someone record your call you will get on call message about your call is getting record

Is there any way to restrict that.

I am working on a app where I would like to record the call incoming/outgoing but the other party should not notify about the call recording.

Does someone has any idea about it?

Comment: Have you discussed your plans with your attorney?

Comment: Read your question again and asked yourself if that would be an ok thing any app could do.

Comment: Yes they want proof of concept about feasibility